# Mapping multiple <select> to <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

It really seems like there should be a better way to do this without pasting scripts to my page, but I'm not very good with js and I could really use some pointing in the right direction. The 'working' code is below.

```
var select;
var i;
select = ['division', 'account_exec', 'badge_printing', 'attendance_tracking', 'lead_retrieval','access_control', 'general_session', 'breakout_rooms', 'exhibit_floor'];
for (i = 0; i < select.length; ++i) {
    $( "<script>$(function(){$('select[name=" + select[i] + "]').change(function(){var selected=$(this).val();$('input[name=input_" + select[i] + "]').val(selected);});});<\/script>" ).appendTo("body");
}
```

Comment: Are the `select` elements not within your `<form>` tag already? If they are, their selected values should automatically get included in the serialized form data without having to store the values in hidden fields.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I feel very dumb right now. I'd still be interested in the solution to my original question for purely academic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with this approach. What you should do is actually tack these names onto the HTML element, rather than an array. What would happen if a name changes, etc? Easier to keep names and IDs, etc in HTML rather than JS - for readability and to reduce errors

You can assign the "ID" to the `data-name` attribute (or whatever you want really).

Example:

```
<div id="someID">
    <select data-name="division">
           <option value="something">Text1</option>
           .....
    </select>
    <input data-name="division" value="" />
    ....
    ....
</div>
```

Now you use the `on` event - and the purpose of doing this is to assign only ONE event to the ID, and tell it to "watch" the selects for the `changed` event.

```
$('#someID').on('change','select', function() {
     var $this = $(this),
         name = $this.data('name'),
         $input = $('#someID').find('input[data-name="' + name + '"]"');

    $input.val($this.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the good-practice explanation. I assume I can combine this withthe response from @Waxi to loop through an array. I'll work on this solution, thanks again.

Comment: Well that's the point, you DON'T need to loop through the array. There's no reason to add an event to every single select, or even do a loop in the first place. The code above in my answer takes care of all of that for you

Comment: Ooohhh, so everything goes in one ID and I monitor all the `<selects>`. I obviously misunderstood, I thought you mean to have a bunch of ID's. This is a _much_ better method. I didn't realize this was an option. I've not used find() before, it's doing some heavy lifting.

Comment: `find()` will look for all children and nested elements that match. Use `children()` when you know the element(s) are immediate children of the selector.

Comment: Theoretically, you don't have to use the `id` approach, you could just assign `class` to every `select` and use like so, `$('select.yourClass').on('change', function() { .. });` but that will assign an `event` to each `select`, rather than just one listener to the ID one. The 2nd reason to use the `on` event is for created elements that need to have this listener attached, as events not using `on` won't apply to those. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look something like this...

```
$(function(){

    var select = [
        'division',
        'account_exec',
        'badge_printing',
        'attendance_tracking',
        'lead_retrieval',
        'access_control',
        'general_session',
        'breakout_rooms',
        'exhibit_floor'
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < select.length; ++i) {

        $('select[name="' + select[i] + '"]').on('change', function(){

            $('input[name="input_' + select[i] + '"]').val($(this).val());

        });

    };

});
```

- You should declare variables as you're assigning them.
- I'm not sure why the ready function was inside the loop, but this normally contains all of the code.
- I'm not sure what you're appending to the body, so I left that out.
- I don't know if `$(this).val()` has the value you're expecting, but you can test it.
- You didn't have the right quotes, so your variables were part of the string.

Comment: I was appending a unique `<script>`to the body. This is the answer I was looking for, thank you.